# Heroku - How to copy MySQL database from one app to another

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have a created an app on Heroku. Let's call it `app_1`. I installed in it JawsBD which provides me a MySQL database with a specific host, username and password.

I want to use this database in another app (let's call it `app_2`) and actually delete `app_1`. If I just install anew JawsDB in `app_2` then I will be provided with a new database (and new host, username and password).

However, I want to use the database of `app_1` and actually delete `app_1`. However, if I delete `app_1` then the database will be lost.

Therefore, how can I copy the MySQL database from `app_1` to `app_2`?

Obviously, I can simply export the tables of the database of `app_1` in a sql file and then import it to `app_2` but I was just wondering if I can transfer the database itself (same host, username, password, database name) by entering one or two lines in terminal.

Comment: You could try to import a backup of the existing DB to a new one as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#database-backups).

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the obvious idea and it can be also done manually pretty easily. My question is more like if I can transfer the database itself (same host, username, password, database name) to `app_2` and totally delete `app_1` in which it was created.